# problem when consulting ip through API php

Tags: php, ip

I am using the service of http://ipinfo.io, I use the following code to consult information of my location through my IP, however, in localhost it works correctly but in the production server no, instead of throwing me the ip from the user, it returns the IP of the server from where the query is made.

I want it to detect the ip of the visitor, not the ip from where the request is made

```
class ipController{
  private $token="XXXXXX";


public function __construct(){

        $handle = curl_init();
        $url = "http://ipinfo.io?token=".$this->token;

        // Set the url
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        // Set the result output to be a string.
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($handle);
         //var_dump($output);  
        curl_close($handle);
        $datos = json_decode($output);
        var_dump($datos); 

        //Se setean las propiedades
        $this->ip = $datos->ip;
        $this->hostname = $datos->hostname;
        $this->city = $datos->city;
        $this->region = $datos->region;
        $this->country = $datos->country;
        $this->loc = $datos->loc;
        $this->postal = $datos->postal;
        $this->org = $datos->org;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You were getting the server IP address because you were sending your
>   request with `curl` and when using the `curl`, the sever does the
>   request with its own IP.

In order to get the visitor's IP address you have to use the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` variables, but this does not return the correct IP address of the visitor sometimes, so you can use the below function to the get the correct IP of the user

```
function get_ip_address() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
}
```

Then you can just get the ip info with the url this way

```
$ip = get_ip_address();
$url = "http://ipinfo.io/$ip?token=$token";

//you can the get the data with
$data = url_get_contents($url);

//curl function to send your request
function url_get_contents($Url) {
  if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
      die('CURL is not installed!');
  }
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you need to put the ip address in the endpoint. Just the token gives your own ip address which is the server

https://ipinfo.io/developers#ip-address-parameter

```
ipinfo.io/$visitors_ip?token=$TOKEN
```

I'd assume it is php making the request to ipinfo hence why you get the servers details